# request url problems when using base href

Tags: apache, angular, angular-cli

**Quick version - What I believe I want:**
How can I configure `angular2 http` service to ignore `<base href>`

**Longer version - In case there is a better approach:**
In my project we are serving two angular apps using Apache:

```
http://host/index.html - angular 1
http://host/ng2/index.html - angular 2
```

They both use the same endpoint

```
http://host/api/foo
```

Both apps are using the same vhost. The angular 2 app is located under public/ng2 on disk.

**The problem boils down to this:**

When I use: `<base href="/ng2/">` the angular app loads fine.
However all requests to the api using the http service gets polluted.

```
http.get('/api/foo/2') goes to http://host/ng2/api/foo
```

My current solution is to set base href to `<base href="/">` and put all angular2 files except index.html directly under /public. (index.html is still in /public/ng2) *This works but it is a mess.*

**What I would like to have:**

- All angular2 files are in /public/ng2 (works because of `<base href="/ng2/">` or other Apache config)
- Outgoing requests do not have ng2 appended to them.

  - e.g http.get('/api/foo/2') => http://host/api/foo

**It is not an option to hardcode the url**

Comment: I would recommand having a $config variable with the full base url of your API for HTTP calls and use http like so : `http.get(api_root + '/foo/2')`

Comment: thanks @KiJéy. What I forgot to mention was that we have multiple instances deployed. Each with its own /api/foo/2. E.g. ( http://customer1-host/api/foo and http://customer2-host/api/foo). So a relative path would be much better.

Comment: Can you explain why you think a relative path would be better? I agree with @KiJéy, put the URL into an environment file an use absolute paths.

Comment: The problem I described above can be solved using absolute paths for sure. When I wrote the question I never seriously considered option to create an absolute path programmatically. E.g
fullUrl = document.location.protocol + "//" + document.location.host + "/" + relativeUrl. This approach does work - so thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I did what Ki Jey suggested and used an absolute url to get to the API.

```
service.base.ts: 
protected getAbsoluteUrl(relativeUrl : String) : String { 
  return document.location.protocol + "//" + document.location.host + "/" + relativeUrl
}

service.ts:
class service extends BaseService
  getTheFoo(){ 
    http.get(this.getAbsoluteUrl(foo/2))...
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

simply appending `'/'` to the api call will stop appending `baseHref` value.

```js
  getFoo(): Observable<any> {
    const url = '/' + 'api/foo';
    return this.http.get<any>(url);
  }
```